# Distinct values from object property in array when property may not be present

Tags: javascript, json, object, javascript-objects

I'm creating an array of distinct values based on a single property in an array of objects. Nothing unusual, but the JSON I'm working with **may** not have that property. The result is I'm getting an item in the new array with a value of `undefined`. Is there a way to prevent this?

```js
const cars = [{
    "name": "Toyota",
    "model": "Corolla"
  },
  {
    "name": "Toyota",
    "model": "Supra"
  },
  {
    "name": "Toyota",
    "model": "Rav4"
  },
  {
    "name": "Toyota"
  }
];

const distinctModels = [...new Set(cars.map(car => car.model))];

console.log(distinctModels);
```

EDIT - I should have mentioned that I'm interested to know if there's a way to do this whilst still utilising `new Set`.

Comment: So might be you will have to check for undefined!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could post process the array and filter falsy values.

```js
const cars = [{ name: "Toyota", model: "Corolla" }, { name: "Toyota", model: "Supra" }, { name: "Toyota", model: "Rav4" }, { name: "Toyota" }];

const distinctModels = [...new Set(cars.map(car => car.model))].filter(Boolean);

console.log(distinctModels);
```

Comment: Can you explain this: `filter(Boolean)`?

Comment: it takes `Boolean` as callback and it returns either `true` for all [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) values and `false` for all others. This allows to filter `undefined`, as well as empty strings.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I should have mentioned that I am doing this, just wondering if there's a way to avoid having to do that.

Comment: @Chris, no there is not. either filter in advance or at the end. i prefer at the end, because the amount of data is smaller to filter.

Comment: Ok, thanks Nina - yours is a more concise way than my current implementation so will use that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.hasOwnProperty` to check if a property exists in the object or not

```js
const cars = [{
    "name": "Toyota",
    "model": "Corolla"
  },
  {
    "name": "Toyota",
    "model": "Supra"
  },
  {
    "name": "Toyota",
    "model": "Rav4"
  },
  {
    "name": "Toyota"
  }
];

const distinctModels = []
cars.forEach(function(e){
e.hasOwnProperty('model')?distinctModels.push(e.model):false;
});
console.log(distinctModels);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter and map at the same time (ie in the one statement) you can instead use `.reduce()` to better control what goes into your output array:

```js
const cars = [{
    "name": "Toyota",
    "model": "Corolla"
  },
  {
    "name": "Toyota",
    "model": "Supra"
  },
  {
    "name": "Toyota",
    "model": "Rav4"
  },
  {
    "name": "Toyota"
  }
];

const distinctModels = [...new Set(cars.reduce(
                         (a, car) => car.model ? [...a, car.model] : a, []
                        ))];

console.log(distinctModels);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.flatMap` to do it in one loop, by returning an empty array when value is not there.

```js
const cars = [{
 "name": "Toyota",
 "model": "Corolla"
},
{
 "name": "Toyota",
 "model": "Supra"
},
{
 "name": "Toyota",
 "model": "Rav4"
},
{
 "name": "Toyota"
}
];

const distinctModels = [...new Set(cars.flatMap(car => car.model || []))];

console.log(distinctModels);
```